# How to Calculate Velocity in a 2D space game

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, physics

I am currently using

```
screenpos.X = (float)(screenpos.X + velocity * Math.Sin(r));
screenpos.Y = (float)(screenpos.Y - velocity * Math.Cos(r));
```

For my Movement with r being the Rotation in Radians. However, I want to know how I can calculate my velocity realistically based on values of Thrust and Mass.

Any Idea's?

Comment: Newton's second law of motion would be a good place to start.

Comment: Yeah. Newton, he was amazing, that's why we celebrate his birthday every 25th of December!

Answer (score 3):

First off, you'll likely have an easier time using vectors for this instead of a float value with rotation separately. (The name `velocity` implies speed and direction, you appear to only be storing a speed and keeping your direction in your `r` value).

Next thing you'll want to acceleration. This will be the change in velocity over time. This is where you'll want to apply your changes to move your object.

So what acts on acceleration? Forces. Forces like gravity and thrust. Force is calculated with F=MA. In this equation you have all the things you want. Mass is the mass of your ship and force is the output of the thruster. Since you want to calculate an acceleration, you can rearrange things to A=F/M. This means each thruster will have a force (a scaled directional vector) and each ship will have a mass. To calculate the acceleration change of that thruster, simply take its force and divide it by the mass of the ship.

There's actually a lot more too this if you want "realistic" values. That's a bit too much to explain here. This should get you started and then you can ask more specific questions as you implement things.

Comment: What makes you think that the OP will want acceleration? Plenty of good space shooters used fixed velocities. (Good advice, though.)

Comment: @ashes999 True, it's not required, but given "*calculate my velocity realistically*", I think acceleration is the best way towards that goal.

Comment: derp, I didn't read that part.

Answer (score 2):

As Fault pointed out, use Newton's second law. Every time-step set your acceleration based on your thrust force (F):

```
a.X = F * Math.Sin(r);
a.Y = F * Math.Cos(r);
```

Then update your velocity:

```
v.X = v.X + a.X * dt;
v.Y = v.Y + a.Y * dt;
```

Finally, update your new position:

```
screenpos.X = screenpos.X + v.X * dt;
screenpos.Y = screenpos.Y + v.Y * dt;
```

dt is the time between two updates. This will give you a realistic behavior including inertia.